# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '0' of undefined happening while trying to load API data with Axios on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Trying to load the Open BreweryDB API in a ReactJS application to display a list of breweries in a US city.  Loading the information using axios and the async componentDidMount() method results in the "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '0' of undefined" error at line 34 (in my code) which would be breweryData = breweryData.data.results[0];

I'm pretty new to ReactJS and API implementation. I tried removing the ...results[0]; portion, but I still got the same error as above, with an issue on the same line.  Not sure how to solve this issue. I'm able to render a "Loading..." element on the card if I ignore the error. Below is the code I am using in my App.js folder

```
import API from './utils/API';
import Brewery from './component/Breweries';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      name: null,
      address: null,
      brewery_type: null
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading, name, address, brewery_type } = this.state;

    return (
      <Brewery isLoading={isLoading} name={name} address={address} brewery_type={brewery_type} />
    );
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let breweryData = await API.get('/', {
      params: {
        results: 1,
        inc: 'name,address,brewery_type'
      }
    });

    breweryData = breweryData.data.results[0];

    const name = `${breweryData.name}`;
    const address = `${breweryData.address}`;
    const brewery_type = `${breweryData.brewery_type}`;

    this.setState({
      ...this.state, ...{
        isLoading: false,
        name,
        address,
        brewery_type
      }
    });
  }
}

export default App;
```

It should display a list of results displaying the name of the brewery, the address, and the brewery type (micro, major, etc.)

Above issue was fixed, however, the API data is not displaying.  Here is the code in the breweries.js file

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "shards-ui/dist/css/shards.min.css";

import { Card } from 'shards-react';

class Brewery extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { name, street, city, state, postal_code, isLoading } = this.props;

        const breweryDetails = (
            <div>
                <h4 className="mb-0">{name}</h4>
                <span className="text-muted">{street}</span>
                <span className="text-muted">{city}</span>
                <span className="text-muted">{state}</span>
                <span className="text-muted">{postal_code}</span>
            </div>
        );

        const loadingMessage = <span className="d-flex m-auto">Loading...</span>;

        return (
            <Card
                className="mx-auto mt-4 text-center p-5"
                style={{ maxWidth: "300px", minHeight: "250px" }}
            >
                {isLoading ? loadingMessage : breweryDetails}
            </Card>
        );
    }
}

Brewery.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string,
    street: PropTypes.string,
    city: PropTypes.string,
    state: PropTypes.string,
    postal_code: PropTypes.string,
    isLoading: PropTypes.bool
};

export default Brewery;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`breweryData = breweryData.data.results[0];`

to

`breweryData = breweryData.data[0]`

or even better

`let returnedBreweryData = breweryData.data ? breweryData.data[0] : {}`

Comment: Also, since this is an API call, you're going to want to be sure the component is still mounted before calling `setState()`

Comment: Edited because your last response answered that question.  I have to fined out why values are undefined, but you helped get me past where I needed. Thanks!

Comment: what's the output of `console.log(breweryData)` after `breweryData = breweryData.data[0]` You may be getting an empty list or nothing at all so when you try to get the data with `breweryData.data[0]` it's null.

Comment: You can protect yourself a bit with something like `const name = breweryData ? brewereyData.name : '';` and `const address = breweryData ? brewereyData.address : '';`

Comment: console.log(breweryData) shows the json document displaying the data, but the React application is not displaying the data.  Edited the original answer to show the Breweries.js file.

Comment: It's because breweries.js is handled through props.  It gets mounted, then the props change, but the mounted component is re-used and no state has changed, so no rerender.  Tap into the https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate lifecycle to compare next props to current props

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe because you are not getting the result from API for some reason.
When you are using async await, you would want to handle the error too.
Add a try catch block to your code and you should be fine

Comment: You are correct, I am not able to get the application to display any of the information, but the request URL in console to show the JSON data.  I haven't really used try catch blocks. Do you have an example?

Comment: Just put your function call in a try block
try {
    // your API get call
  } catch (error) {
    // catch error here
  }

Comment: I just saw your props issue. 
You are passing props: name, address and brewery_type but not destructuring these instead you are destructuring following  name, street, city, state, postal_code.
You should use same name for destructuring

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update the original code, those props have been updated to match the destructuring.  Items are still not visible, however.

Comment: When you are calling setState in componentDidMount don't destructure this.state
Just do this
this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        name,
        address,
        brewery_type
    });

Comment: @lbtsam My apologies, yes my problems were solved.  I am now generating the correct data and am moving into figuring out how multiple pages work. Thanks!